# Runnig an application in the background

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently working on a project developing a servlet for a program.

This servlet does not listen for requests, instead I want it to run in the background and execute every 10 seconds.

I am using `Thread.sleep(10000);` to accomplish this.

What is the best way to have this servlet execute every 10 seconds while simultaneously allowing other processes to run?

Comment: If coding a servlet, you will need to deploy it in a servlet container. Apache Tomcat is one of the easiest to work with. The servlet container will allow other requests to be processed by running them on separate threads.

Comment: @Hans Hansen what do you mean by servlet? see [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html]

Comment: I guess I should reword it and just say a program. This is a web application that is deployed through a WAR file. I need to attach a program to it that can run in the background and query a db. I have the program running correctly. The biggest issue right now is that running it as a servlet is stopping all other processes from executing. Therefore I am guessing it is not in fact supposed to be a servlet and instead it is supposed to be something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Post some code, please. Then we might be able to tell how it could block other threads or even processes.

Comment: I would say you shouldn't do this. Instead look into EJB3 timer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SingleThreadPool and execute it using a QuartzScheduler. So you can change how often you want it to execute by changin only the configuration file. Your thread becames a job, you can assign priority, etc.

Here is documentation to read:

1. [Scheduling and Thread Pooling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/scheduling.html)
2. [what is Quartz](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/09/28/what-is-quartz.html?page=2)
3. ...and [a tutorial on Quartz](http://www.roseindia.net/quartz/index.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a servlet for this. It won't work reliably for you because servlets are specifically designed to respond to requests. Instead, use a [ServletContextInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to [schedule a TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that does your background work.

Comment: I believe this will work however I have run into a problem. I need the WAR to actually load all of its files before I attempt to run my program.

Let me explain further:

There is a properties file I need the system to load in order for me to run my method call it method(). method() returns an error if this file does not exist (the file does not exist until the entire WAR has been successfully loaded) because of this I am wondering if there is a way for me to delay the creation of the context listener until after the WAR is deployed?

Comment: Then the way you're loading the properties file is wrong. Fix that, and then you won't have a problem. If you need direction on that, I suggest asking another SO question to give the relevant deatils.